# Akka: How many dispatchers per actor system?

Tags: akka, dispatcher

This is more of a best practices question. Though it does affect performance.

How many dispatchers should I have in one application or actor system?
Is it alright to have for example one dispatcher for consumers, one for producers, one for management...? Or should I keep the number of dispatchers to a bare minimum?

EDIT:
What about blocking I/O operations - reading from a socket for example?
Should the actors who do this have a separate dispatcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not blocking (managed or unmanaged) threads then one dispatcher is fine.

Otherwise do not do blocking :). If you really need to, do blocking in a separate dispatcher.

Comment: I never block.
But my thoughts are: What if I want to set the limit number of threads for worker actors separately from management actors? Is this something I should worry about?